# Why it is showing Index error and Incomplete data scrape while doing python web scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the web page "https://global.oup.com/academic/content/series/v/very-short-introductions-vsi/?type=listing&lang=en&cc=in" after I run the script, it gives the indexerror. On the site, There are about 739 books total and after I run the script, the downloaded excel sheet it is showing 719. Please help me with the script, why it is giving the Indexerror and Why it is only scraping the 719 books?

```
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import openpyxl

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

excel = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = 'avsi'
sheet.append(['Titles', 'Price', 'Author', 'ISBN', 'Paperback', 'Date'])
              
pages = np.arange(0,800,100)
for page in pages:
    page = requests.get("https://global.oup.com/academic/content/series/v/very-short-introductions-vsi/?prevNumResPerPage=100&prevSortField=1&resultsPerPage=100&sortField=1&type=listing&start="+str(page)+"&lang=en&cc=in")
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    sleep(randint(2,8))
    books = soup.find('div', class_='search_result_list').find_all('tr')
    #print(len(books))
    for book in books:
        titles = book.find_all('td', class_='result_biblio')
        for title in titles:
            name = title.find('a').text
            #print(len(name))
            price = title.select('p')[2].text
            author = title.select('p')[3].text
            #print(name)
            isbn = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[1]
            paperback = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[2]
            date = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[3]
            month = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[4]
            year = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[5]
            #data = [name,price,author]
            #data = [name,price,author,isbn]
            data = [name,price,author,isbn,paperback,date+" "+month+" "+year]
            sheet.append(data)
            excel.save('avs1.xlsx')
```

Comment: **We need to know the exact error, not a summary.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe some book doesn't have all values and code can't get some index ie. `[3]`. You could use `print()` to see what you really get from page, and which book makes problem. And then you can check in browser if this book really doesn't have some value. And you may need to use `try/except` to catch error for element and set some default value or None

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AbidFakhreAlam\Downloads\VSI1.py", line 33, in <module>
    isbn = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: from the URL it is showing 100 records on every page and there are about 7 pages and on the last page, there are only 39 records.

Comment: the error is in item number 719, there is only a title is there, no other thing like author, isbn, paperback, date etc. because of that the index error is showing. How to correct this.

Comment: @AbidFakhrealam: That is  the conclusion of my answer, you have to check and handle all these information. Yes, I could provide a full example later, but at first it is your task to try and understand. So take minute, check all your scraped information with `try/except` or select more specific.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is only scraping the 719 books?

Answer is simple, iterating over the books of a page, you append a book and save the excel sheet per iteration and this is where your error message comes into game. Script stops and thus the number of books / lines in your excel sheet does not increase any more - It is therefore quite obvious that the error is to be found at this point.

> Why it is giving the Indexerror?

You are working on `ResultSets` and pick your information by index, assuming that the index must exist in each and every result. But there is one book on the last page, close to the end you could not add to cart and that causes the error.

###### How to fix?

Select your books more specific e.g. only these you could add to cart:

```
books = soup.select('.search_result_list tr:has(div.result_add)')
```

Or check if information you are searching for is available and handle that situation to your needs:

```
...
try:
    isbn = title.select('p')[4].text.split(" ")[1]
except:
    isbn = None
...
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import openpyxl

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

excel = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = 'avsi'
sheet.append(['Titles', 'Price', 'Author', 'ISBN', 'Paperback', 'Date'])

pages = np.arange(0,800,100)
for page in pages:
    page = requests.get("https://global.oup.com/academic/content/series/v/very-short-introductions-vsi/?prevNumResPerPage=100&prevSortField=1&resultsPerPage=100&sortField=1&type=listing&start="+str(page)+"&lang=en&cc=in")
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    sleep(randint(1,5))
    books = soup.select('.search_result_list tr')
    for book in books:
        titles = book.find_all('td', class_='result_biblio')
        for title in titles:
            name = title.find('a').text
            price = title.select('p')[2].text
            author = title.select('p')[3].text
            ###cause all following information is placed in same tag it would be okay group the try/except
            try:
                isbn = title.select('p')[4].text.split(' ')[1]
                paperback = title.select('p')[4].text.split(' ')[2]
                date = ' '.join(title.select('p')[4].text.split(' ')[3:6])
            except:
                isbn,paperback,date = (None,)*3

            data = [name,price,author,isbn,paperback,date]
            sheet.append(data)
            excel.save('avs1.xlsx')
```

Comment: I tried, now the error is not showing but it is scraping only 718 books but there is about 739 books.

Comment: When I print(books), it gives the [] this.

Comment: Success, Now I scrape all 739 books with try and except method. I have a question I put in every field try and except, is there any way to mention I one place, not in every field. and how to join the date, month and year .

Comment: for title in titles:
            try:
                name = title.find('a').text
            except:
                name = None
            try:
                price = title.select('p')[2].text
            except:
                price = None
            try:
                author = title.select('p')[3].text
            except:
                author = None

Comment: Great - Added an example based on your comment, take a look and try.